# How to retrieve table values from database one by one in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i want to retrieve particular table values from database and need to assign each values to each variable in mvc5. My question is little tricky and maybe some times it will confuse you dudes. I will explain my issue clearly

[Employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzC92.jpg)

This is my employee table and it contain 2 fields called EmployeeID and DisplayName . EmployeeID is primary key. What i need is i want to retrieve these tables values one by one and assign that values (Which i retrieve one by one from table  ) to variables.

Eg

```
 var1 = yasin
 var2 = rajan..
```

I tried one method . In that  method i gave hardcode to find each Id one by one. But hardcode is not correct way for  professional developer right.

[retrieved value using Hardcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laAW2.jpg)

See the above image in that i found  the ID of each employee from employee table by using Hardcode.

Eg

```
    var yasinempid = (from emp in db.Employees where emp.DisplayName == "Yasin" select emp.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now i want to find the ID of yasin employee.so i gave yasin value directly in the query. But this is not correct way because i have limited no of employees so i can able to find employee ID  easily . But i have lot of employees means this hardcode value is not correct way and also it wont give correct solution right . So  that i need alternate solution for this problem.

I tried my level best to explain this issue. Any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this problem.

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this;

1. Fetch all the records and convert them to a list of Employees.

   `List<Employees> Emps=db.Employees.toList();`
2. Loop through the list of Employees as you assign the variables.

   `foreach(Employee emp in Emps)
       {
           var1 =emp.DisplayName;
           var2=emp.printName;
           var3 =emp.EmployeeID;
       }`

Comment: Any comments to make it better is highly appreciated

Comment: Actually what i want is var 1= yasin  var 2 = Rithubaran  var3 = jagadesshwaran like that

Comment: that is var 1 = yasinID("C19EF560-9BC2-490A-9E92-3D694EC9DC05") i need each Employee ID and i want to assing that each employee ID to each variable

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?
If yes, then object `Employee` has all the parameters as fetched from DB by `EF` 

`EF` picks DB objects with all their parameter. so `Employee` will come with EmpID as well and you can manipulate them as you wish.

Comment: Yes i am using EF only

Comment: Please share the snippet for the modal

Comment: you asking model of the table